# When does the lifespan of the OS Windows XP expire?

Tags: windows

When does XP expire? From what I hear is it 2011, is this true?
http://www.downloadsquad.com/2009/06/18/microsoft-extends-windows-xp-lifespan-through-2011/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Extended support for Windows XP ends on the second Tuesday of April 2014, after the last security updates are released for that month.

[Source (MS Support)](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?LN=en-gb&C2=1173)

Comment: Maybe they will implement an Extra Extended support retired? hehe ;)

Comment: Unlikely. Microsoft actually wants XP to die a pretty fast death because it's a disaster to support.

Answer (score 3):

XP's lifespan has been extended quite a number of times - initially the lifespan was supposed to end just shortly after the release of Vista.

Microsoft has officially stated that support lifespan for XP will end April 2011, but it is anybody's guess as to whether it will be extended again.

However, given the positive reception of Windows 7 from consumers and enterprises, there is a huge chance that April 2011, about 9 years 6 months from when it first launched in Oct 2001, XP will have a chance to put its shoes up and have a good rest.

Comment: also bound to happen in April 2011: MS will pull the plug on the XP activation server.

Answer (score 3):

if you count **Windows XP Professional x64 for Embedded System**, EoL (End of Life) is currently scheduled for April 25, 2020. :)

Source: [Windows XP End of Life](http://www.fabrimex.com.tw/file/download/10/Windows%20XP%20End%20of%20Life.pdf) (PDF)

Comment: AFAIK patches for MS's embedded OSes are distributed using a private extranet (ECE): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee832774.aspx